# Vb to C# code conversion with Raise Event

Tags: gridview, vb.net-to-c#

I am trying to convert the code for the following method.
I am not sure how to go about it since there isn't a equivalent in C# to raise event.

What I want to happen is the `Gridview` page index changing gets bubbled up to my UI so I can do some code in the event right now nothing happens because this is a custom pager template class that is set to the gridview.

```
    public delegate void PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e);
     public event  PageIndexChanging PagerPageIndexChanging;

    Private Sub NextLinkBtn_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NextLinkBtn.Click

    Dim gridView As GridView = _container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer

    If (gridView.PageIndex < gridView.PageCount - 1) Then
        gridView.PageIndex = gridView.PageIndex + 1

    End If

    FormatPager(gridView)

    'Raise PagerPageIndexChanging, passing it the GridView instance using this custom pager template.
    RaiseEvent PagerPageIndexChanging(gridView, New GridViewPageEventArgs(gridView.PageIndex))

End Sub
```

More Detail on the question.

I have a gridview on a aspnet page. I have a class level variable for the pagertemplate

```
 public PagerTemplate GridPagerTemplate = new PagerTemplate();
```

Then in the grids init method I attach the gridpager template to the grids.PagerTemplate... Everything works it does the first next prev last etc... The problem I am having is after I converted the code from Vb.net to C# That I cant raise the event from the PagerTemplate class in order to get it to execute on the webpage...

```
protected void ui_grdGuests_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     if (GridPagerTemplate != null)
       {

          ui_grdGuests.PagerTemplate = GridPagerTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Trying to put a break point here in the web form because this is where I need to get it to come after executing the code in the pagertemplate.

```
protected void ui_grdGuests_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured it out.  Here is how I did it.

Pager template has a delegate and an event

```
 public delegate void PageIndexChangingHandler(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e);

        public event PageIndexChangingHandler PagerPageIndexChanging;


        private void NextLinkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            _gridView = _container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer as GridView;


            if (_gridView != null && (_gridView.PageIndex < _gridView.PageCount - 1))
            {
                _gridView.PageIndex = _gridView.PageIndex + 1;
                _gridView.SelectedIndex = -1;

            }

            FormatPager(_gridView);

            //Raise PagerPageIndexChanging, passing it the GridView instance using this custom pager template.
            if (PagerPageIndexChanging != null)
            {
                PagerPageIndexChanging(_gridView, new GridViewPageEventArgs(_gridView.PageIndex));
            }
        }
```

on the web form  I did  subscribed to that event...

```
 GridPagerTemplate.PagerPageIndexChanging += new Classes.PagerTemplate.PageIndexChangingHandler(GridPagerTemplate_PagerPageIndexChanging);

  void GridPagerTemplate_PagerPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, it looks like the following:

```
if (PagerPageIndexChanging != null)[
{
    PagerPageIndexChanging(gridView, new GridViewPageEventArgs(gridView.PageIndex))
}
```

Beforehand, you will need to subscribe to the event somewhere, such as:

```
gridview.PagerPageIndexChanging += gridview_PagerPageIndexChanging;
```

where `gridview_PagerPageIndexChanging` is a method with the same signature as your delegate above.

Comment: I guess I am not fully understanding... The GridView doesnt have a PagerPageIndexChanging  event it has a  _gridView.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(this._gridView_PageIndexChanging); so i tried doing that but  when it gets back to the web page it never goes to the pageIndexchanging method back on the webpage. I will edit my question to try and explain more.